# Nesting errors in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm creating a program that is required to  read values from two arrays (ARR and MRK), counting each set of values (I,J) in order to determine their frequency for a third array (X). I've written the following so far, but nesting errors are preventing the program from compiling. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL, DIMENSION (0:51, 0:51) :: MRK, ALT
INTEGER :: I, J                    !! FREQUENCY ARRAY ALLELES
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: K = 2
INTEGER :: M, N                    !! HAPLOTYPE ARRAY POSITIONS
INTEGER :: COUNTER = 0
REAL, DIMENSION(0:1,0:K-1):: X

ALT = 8
MRK = 8
X = 0

MRK(1:50,1:50) = 0                  !! HAPLOTYPE ARRAY WITHOUT BUFFER AROUND OUTSIDE
ALT(1:50,1:50) = 0

DO I = 0, 1                         !! ALTRUIST ALLELE    
    DO J = 0, K-1                   !! MARKER ALLELE
        DO M = 1, 50
            DO N = 1, 50            !! READING HAPLOTYPE POSITIONS

                IF ALT(M,N) = I .AND. MRK(M,N) = J THEN
                    COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
                ELSE IF ALT(M,N) .NE. I .OR. MRK(M,N) .NE. J THEN
                    COUNTER = COUNTER + 0
                END IF

                X(I,J) = COUNTER/2500
                COUNTER = 0

            END DO
        END DO
    END DO
END DO
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `if` syntax is incorrect. You should enclose the conditional expressions between brackets. Also, I think you should replace single `=` by a double `==` in the same expressions and maybe keep the syntax type to either `==` and `/=` or `.eq.` and `.neq.`, but not mix them:

```
IF (ALT(M,N) == I .AND. MRK(M,N) == J) THEN
  COUNTER = COUNTER + 1
ELSE IF (ALT(M,N) /= I .OR. MRK(M,N) /= J) THEN
  COUNTER = COUNTER + 0
END IF
```

I don't know if in your actual program you do it, but you should probably use `program program_name` and `end program program_name` at the very beginning and very end of your code, respectively, where `program_name` is anything you want to call your program (no spaces allowed I think), although a simple `end` at the end would suffice.

Comment: +1, but the `program/end program` is more or less just a question of good style. Single `end` a the end of the program is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have updated my answer accordingly.